# backup db to amazon s3 bucket with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to backup db to amazon s3. I created bucket, entered credentials to my env file and installed "spatie/laravel-backup" package. I followed this [link](https://tuts.codingo.me/laravel-backup-amazon-s3) to set everything up. When I run `php artisan backup:run`, I get this message:

"Laravel-backup notifier failed because Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"

This is my [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3hujRIgFlgAR1hMQWtpVzR1STg) file.

Comment: Use this package which will help you to take instant backup of entire database on S3 storage. `https://github.com/fitztrev/laravel-mysql-s3-backup`

Comment: Now, when I added mailgun to my app, I  get this message:

"Free accounts are for test purposes only. Please upgrade or add the address to authorized recipients in  (truncated...)"

I'm sending emails with no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by entering valid email address in laravel-backup.php, to "mail" key.